# Editing force_ssl option in shop.json of a Shopify store

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, shopify

Towards the end of February, Shopify set the force_SSL option true (even for dev stores) which is a problem for me because I'm working on a Shopify app locally (using localhost) and my computer doesn't have a SSL cert.

Is there any way to change this option in the admin of a Shopify store? If so how?

If not (I have the feeling that this isn't possible...) is there a way I can get a localhost SSL cert? I'm using Node.JS and Express.JS and two ports to run my app (port 2000) and my website (port 3000).

Comment: You'd get a better response from Shopify forums or support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm the absolute biggest idiot ever... My new dev store was password protected, therefore it had the http header of X-Frame-Options set to DENY. When I removed the password everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You're unable to turn off `force_ssl` yourself - however there shouldn't really be a need to do so.

Are you running into a particular error when developing? There may be some ways around it.

Outside of that, you can always check out [OpenSSL](https://github.com/openssl/openssl).

Comment: I'm trying to develop an app locally but my localhost doesn't have SSL. Will Open SSL let me put a cert on my localhost?

Comment: I don't think you should need it, but yes, it will let you put a cert on your localhost. If you're just having trouble viewing the embedded app, you can typically click the shield in Chrome and allow http to be loaded.

Comment: I'm not having issues with that– I'm having issues with making get requests that give me information about specific products (producthandle.json). Here's a link that explains what I mean: https://docs.shopify.com/api/reference/product

Comment: Hmm, not sure if that's going to be because of SSL. I run an app on localhost without an SSL cert.

What's the request you're making? Are you doing a GET to `/products.json` or to a specific product `/products/<product_id>.json`? If you're GETting a specific product, then trying to retrieve the handle, you would simply make a request to `/products/<product_id>.json` then from within the response, you would then retrieve the handle.

Comment: Well actually in the documentation it says the following about force_ssl: "Indicates whether the shop forces requests made to its resources to be made over SSL, using the HTTPS protocol. If true, HTTP requests will be redirected to HTTPS." https://docs.shopify.com/api/reference/shop. I have one dev store that I created before Shopify made the force_ssl option true even for dev stores (so its force_ssl option is false) and my app works there. I wanted to test my app out on multiple different stores though, so I was looking for a way to to turn force_ssl off.

Comment: If you put both http and https localhost as your **Redirection URL** like so:  
`http://localhost:3000/auth/shopify/callback` `https://localhost:3000/auth/shopify/callback`  
Does that make any difference?

Comment: No it doesn't :( I actually ended up pushing all of my code to Heroku (which has SSL) and it turns out the SSL wasn't the only issue... I'm using an iframe in my app and I need to make get requests to the retrieve product info and it seems like Shopify has set the X-Frame-Options http header to DENY for all new stores... I have no clue on how to work around this. Any ideas??